# Not able to open SQLiteDatabase created by PHP

Tags: php, android, sqlite

Hi I created a SQLite database using the code below.

```
$db = new SQLiteDatabase("train");
@$db->queryExec("CREATE TABLE words(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,word TEXT,meaning TEXT,sentence TEXT)");
$query = "CREATE TABLE android_metadata(locale TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US')";
                @$db->queryExec($query);
                $query = "INSERT INTO android_metadata(locale) VALUES ('en_US')";
                @$db->queryExec($query);
```

I tried to open the above database file using SQLLite Database browser 2.0 b1 but its showing
"An error occurred: File is not a SQLite 3 database".
Is it expected??

Also when I try to open the database in android its showing the following error 
"Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database"

but I have the table android_metadata with column locale and I have inserted one row also..

Why is this happening? Anything wrong in database creation?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android uses SQLite3, you're not.

PHP has [SQLite 3 support](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.sqlite3.php) though.